# Explorer.exe does not starts itself at the startup

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-explorer

The problem I am facing is whenever I start my PC after use login window where it should show the start screen my PC just doesn’t show anything except for a mouse cursor.

I can press `CTRL` `ALT` `DELETE` and go into task manager go into `File` > `Run New Task` and then run `explorer.exe` sometimes this works and start screen becmoes accesible but sometimes I have to repeat it multiple times to make it work or sometimes I just have to restart my PC.

More over while on the black screen and being able to access task manager If I right click processes there and `open containing folder` that also work I can access all my program/files from there but all that is missing is my `desktop` and `start screen`

- Can anybody help me with this?
- Plus can anybody tell like for explorer there is `explorer.exe` is there a `.exe` file which would start the start screen ?

Answer (score 3):

There's a registry key that tells Windows what "shell" to load on startup.  Open regedit, and look for the key here:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon

Make sure that the shell key is set to be explorer.exe.

Source: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itprogeneral/thread/eba53d03-1dda-4d56-8208-964cdee3b77a/

Update: If there is explorer.exe and csrcs.exe, you should delete csrcs.exe from there.

Comment: its alread set to `explorer.exe`

Answer (score 1):

I found that in at least one case, the `HKEY_LOCAL_USER` one had been modified. So also check:

> HKEY_LOCAL_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon

There might also be a "Shell" key in there. For my case it was there and had the value of `cmd.exe`.  I changed it to `explorer.exe` to fix it as stated above.

Answer (score 0):

Open your services application using the CTRL ALT DEL + Run method. You should be able to CTRL F to find explorer.exe in there and make sure that it's running state is set to automatic. This way it will automatically boot when you login.

Usually this gets turned off by a virus so I would suggest doing a full scan of your machine using something like malware bytes and a virus checker such as security essentials.